# How to look up value that's generic text, not X?

Tags: excel

This value is looking up ="x" but how can I make it look up any text/number/generic value in cell range?

```
 =IF(OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A$1,B3,C3)="x",OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A$1,B3,0),"")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What is your scenario? If "any text/number/generic value" is in A1, then just replace `"x"` with `A1`. But you probably wouldn't ask if it were that easy. So what makes it more complex? - Edit your question to provide clarification. Do NOT do that in a comment. Post a comment when you're done editing your question to alert people following the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(OFFSET('BIBS & TOPIC ASSIGN'!$A$1,B3,C3)<>"",OFFSET('BIBS & TOPIC ASSIGN'!$A$1,B3,0),"")
```

Comment: It would be considerably more helpful if you edit the answer to explain why it is a good answer and to lay it out so it is readable.